# How to pass string and int from one activity to another in Android across different projects in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

I am trying to send a set of  data from one Activity under project A , package a , into another Activity under project B , package b for Android project integration.

How to modify the Intent myintent = new Intent () in order can such be achieved?

The below is my part of code of project A, package a ..

```
try {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent();
    Bundle myData = new Bundle();
    myData.putInt("cntKey", contractKey);
    myData.putInt("workTypeKey", workType);
    myData.putInt("estateIDKey", estateID);
    myData.putInt("workIDKey", workID);
    myData.putInt("blockIDKey", blockID);
    myData.putInt("districtIDKey", districtID);
    myData.putString("estateRoomNumKey", estateRoomNumber);
    myData.putString("estateKey", estate);
    myData.putString("blockKey", block);
    myIntent.putExtras(myData);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

---

Now I am trying to pass some data from one Activity , package a , project A into another Activity, package b , Project B

The Project A itself is a library project.

What should I begin with if using Indents and Bundle?

Comment: you can use aidl, this link will help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591281/example-of-aidl-use

Comment: what ?? you mean different packages??

Comment: do you want to pass data between two activities present in different packages or between two activities present in different sub packages but under a common package??

Comment: and under different Android projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to use is a broadcast.

Comment: what about if the values of these variables are only used within these Activities ? 3

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify project B also, I would just go with

```
myIntent = new Intent("some.very.unique.id.that.you.define")
```

and then declare an [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ifs) for that id in the Android manifest of activity B in package B.

Other activities of third party party apps could also register the same intent filter, so don't use this solution if you want to transfer sensitive data. In such a case, the full solution would probably be [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html).