# How does ContentProvider work internally

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Everyone,I was looking at android source.But I could not find something valuable for me.Actually,I want to know whether `ContentProvider` is worked like `AIDL`.You know ,`AIDL` can achieve the communication between two independence application.

So, I just want to see how does the `ContentProvider` work internally.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/8591438/444324

Comment: oh,Thank you for your reply..yeah,it said the ContentProvider is based on the AIDL,it's useful for me! If the answer can explain more about how does the ContentProvidor work internally,in source code,will be much better. Anyway,thanks very much!

Comment: from what I understand, exactly the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

From ContentProvider [Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/content/ContentProvider.java#ContentProvider)

> Content providers are one of the primary building blocks of Android
>   applications, providing content to applications. They encapsulate data
>   and provide it to applications through the single ContentResolver
>   interface. A content provider is only required if you need to share
>   data between multiple applications. For example, the contacts data is
>   used by multiple applications and must be stored in a content
>   provider. If you don't need to share data amongst multiple
>   applications you can use a database directly via
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.

According to this and to the information in the link I sent you, ContentProvider **isn't** using AIDL... It is using the ContentResolver interface.

Comment: hi,Liorry.Thanks for your reply..I am agree with you that the ContentProvider is using the ContentResolver interface.But How dose it achieve that expose the data to other applications ? Accroding to this [link](stackoverflow.com/a/8591438/444324) I think it's AIDL.But I am not quite sure. What do you think of ?

Comment: @user1727934 unlike AIDL, contentProvider doesn't allow communication between applications. It only allows data sharing. I think it's based on the same way you can share your sharedPreferences (Activity.MODE_WORLD_READABLE/WRITABLE). It's just a flag that tells the system you allow public access to this file/SQL db. Same as Android itself reveals the contacts, bookmarks, etc... they use a contentProvider.

Answer (score 1):

Content Providers use IPC Binders internally. "In fact, Intents and ContentProvider are just a higher-level abstraction of Binder"